# vCenter 5 crashes unexpectedly

Tags: vmware-vcenter

I am having an issue with my vCenter 5 essentials server. We've been running this server for approx 2 years, and about a month ago this problem popped up. Seemingly out of the blue the server crashes, however the issue is resolved with a reboot of the machine.

The following is information that would be worth while.

- When the server crashes you cannot login to it via vSphere and it stops sending alert e-mails
- When server crashes you can *sometimes* log into the console, but not always
- The server will respond to ping after it's crashed
- I've looked at the `/var/log/messages` right after a crash but nothing really jumped out at me (I may have missed something, I'm not a linux guru by any means)
- The crashes happen sporadically with no real rhyme or reason (that I can see) as to when they might happen.

I have also noticed some "Stateless" alarms have shown up as of late but I'm not sure if they're related. I've researched them but can't find a whole lot on them. An example is below.

> Target: Datacenters
>   Stateless event alarm
>   Alarm Definition: 
>   ([Event alarm expression: Status change])
>   Event details:
>   vCenter Management Webservices status changed from green to yellow

I'm not sure if these are related. Does anyone know where I can look to try and figure out why these crashes are happening? Perhaps a log file I've missed.

EDIT 
vCenter is a virtual appliance. 5.0.0.3324 Build 472350

ESXi Host #1 (hosts vCenter appliance) : 5.0.0, 623860
ESXi Host #2 5.0.0, 623860
ESXi Host #3 4.1.0, 260247

Comment: Does the server become unresponsive or does it crash, because those are not the same thing.

Comment: Please provide the version and build number of your vCenter and ESXi hosts Also, are you using a vCenter appliance? Are you running it on Windows?

Comment: @joeqwerty the server crashes - I will change the question accordingly.

Comment: @ewwhite edited question to reflect your questions

Answer (score 1):

These are [really, really old builds](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6195/im-tired-of-answering-questions-with-upgrade-the-firmware-or-run-updates) of VMware, vCenter appliance and ESXi - *circa 2011*. Too much has changed since then. You should really be on vSphere 5.1 or 5.5 at this juncture.

If you have an active support contract, check with VMware to see the ideal upgrade path to a more stable revision. VMware doesn't expect that anyone is still using these versions of the software.